# Dynamic JSON Checking for API Test Suite

Tags: json, performance, api, chai

I am currently working on an open-source API Testing suite that works in conjunction with an awesome REST client called [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en).

With my Test Suite I run a series of API calls that check the response against an expected JSON object/array (or whatever). I think I have a good structure for comparing the two while still allowing the response/expected to be dynamic.

I have figured out the dynamic portion by allowing (mustache-esque) syntax to denote dynamic portions of the response. Basically, if a a value is formatted as `{{content}}` it handles it accordingly. The different values here will be: `NOT_NULL`, `STRING`, `ARRAY`, `OBJECT`, and `NUMBER`.

The sudo-code I have for this function looks like this:

```
function (response, expected) {
    if expected has `{{}}` syntax {
        switch syntax
            check response type of against expected type of ({{type}})
                set flag if failure
                return
    } else {
        if response is the same type as expected {
            switch based on type of response
                case string
                    check if response/request are equal
                    set flag if failure
                    return
                case array
                    check if response/request are equal
                    set flag if failure
                    return
                case object
                    for key in object
                        call this function with response[key] and request[key]
        } else {
            set flag (failure)
            return
        } 
    } 
}
```

I *think* this will work properly, but I wanted to check and see if there were any obvious things I missed when coming up with this checker or if there is a more efficient way of doing this pretty complicated check.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

After going through my sudo-code, it looks like I had an awkward check that would not give me my expected result. The function above has been updated to *hopefully* work properly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research and trial and error, this is what I came up with. It probably isn't perfect, but for lack of any other suggestions it is what I am going with:

```
checkJSON: (response, expected) ->
    if /{{2}(STRING|NOT_NULL|ARRAY|OBJECT|NUMBER|IGNORE)}{2}/.test(expected)
        switch expected
            when '{{STRING}}'
                console.log 'testing string!'
                unless typeof(response) is 'string'
                    console.log 'TYPE OF WAS SUPPOSED TO BE STRING: '+ typeof(response)
                    @failure = true
                    return
            when '{{NOT_NULL}}'
                console.log 'testing not null!'
                unless response
                    console.log 'TYPE OF WAS SUPPOSED TO BE NOT_NULL: '+ typeof(response)
                    @failure = true
                    return
            when '{{ARRAY}}'
                console.log 'testing array!'
                unless Object::toString.call(response) is '[object Array]'
                    console.log 'TYPE OF WAS SUPPOSED TO BE OBJECT (ARRAY): '+ typeof(response)
                    @failure = true
                    return
            when '{{OBJECT}}'
                console.log 'testing object!'
                unless typeof(response) is 'object'
                    console.log 'TYPE OF WAS SUPPOSED TO BE OBJECT: '+ typeof(response)
                    @failure = true
                    return
            when '{{NUMBER}}'
                console.log 'testing number!'
                unless typeof(response) is 'number'
                    console.log 'TYPE OF WAS SUPPOSED TO BE NUMBER: '+ typeof(response)
                    @failure = true
                    return
            when '{{IGNORE}}'
                console.log 'IGNORING THIS OUTPUT!'
            #not really necessary because of regex, but good to check
            else
                console.log 'HOW DID YOU GET HERE?!?!?!'
                @failure = true
                return
    else
        if typeof(response) is typeof(expected)
            switch typeof(response)
                when 'string', 'number'
                    unless response is expected
                        console.log 'Response did not equal Expected!'
                        @failure = true
                        return
                when 'object'
                    if Object::toString.call(response) is '[object Array]'
                        #compare arrays
                        unless response.length is expected.length
                            console.log response.length +' was supposed to equal '+ expected.length
                            @failure = true
                            return
                        #need to do more checks, but this will work for now...
                        #LINK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript
                    else
                        for key of response
                            if typeof(expected[key]) != 'undefined'
                                @checkJSON(response[key], expected[key])
                            else
                                console.log 'KEY WAS INCORRECT!'
                                @failure = true
                                return
        else
            @failure = true
            return
```

The code above is in coffeeScript if anyone is interested.